# PHP Getting different of 2 times in seconds

Tags: php, date, time

I know this has been asked before, but I cannot get it working for me.

```
$from = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
$to = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($row['clock']));
$diffInSeconds = $to - $from;
```

the $row['clock'] = 2013-10-30 15:56:51

This always returns 0.

I just need the amount of minutes and seconds between the dates.

Thanks

Comment: How could we know what's in your `$row['clock']` ? May be a little pony is sitting there, so use `var_dump()` to discover that

Comment: @AlmaDo Basically, he is subtracting string.

Answer (score 1):

You're simply subtracting two strings. That's why you're getting the result as 0. You should first find the difference between the timestamps and ***then*** use [`date()`](http://php.net/date) to create your date string:

```
$from = time();
$to = strtotime($row['clock']);
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $to - $from);
```

Comment: Oops yes it works. used i:s to just get hours minutes. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`date` function returns a string containing a formatted date, NOT an actual date value. You want to look at converting to a numeric value that represents the date/time using `strtotime` and then finding the difference between those two values.